# How to open alert or popup in email

Tags: javascript, html, email

My requirement is as followed: I need to send an email that contains a link, and when an user clicks on that link a popup should open. I read https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp on how to open a popup, but when i opened the link from a mail in thunderbird it didn't open any popup. I tried this with alert(); too but again, the popup didn't work. Could I use bootstrap to do this?

I used Javascript and onClick() function to show the alert.

Answer (score 1):

Most email clients will not execute your JavaScript. This cannot be worked around.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure no malicious code can be automatically executed on the opening of an email, all safe mail clients prohibit the execution of any code when opening a mail - with an exception for HTML of course.

What you can do however, is linking to a webpage that the recipient will open. Then, using Javascript's onLoad option, display an alert. That would look something like this:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body onload="alert('Your message!')"
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Simply click 'Run code snippet' to test it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can't include any third party library in your email as most email engine won't render that third party library. 
Email is not to be for interaction rather then they are to give information about particular things.

You can refer this [Link](https://mailchimp.com/email-design-guide/) for email Guidelines.